# Can 'properties' or 'fields' be explicitly typed in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I'm coming from a C# background, where we have `fields` and `properties`.

JavaScript supports classes, and I'm learning about them but hit a hurdle immediately.

The following code snippet works fine but my question is about the 2 "fields" `mass` and `moons`. JavaScript is creating these objects but I'd like to know if they can be created explicitly.

```
class Planet {

      constructor (mass, moons) {
        this.mass  = mass;
        this.moons = moons || 0;
      }

      reportMoons () {
        txt.innerHTML = "I have " + this.moons + " moons.";
      }
}
```

The code [source](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them)

So somehow (I believe as the variables are not defined, it *should* be automatically made a global variable but as it's part of a class I suspect it's not doing that either), JavaScript knows about `mass` and `moons`. I'd rather see these variables declared explicitly (as I would in C#) but I can't add a `var`, `const` or `let` within the class. The following is not valid

```
class Planet {  

   constructor (mass, moons) {
   }

   let _mass;
   const _val = 5;
}
```

The reason is I think it's easier to look for the properties defined instead of having to look into the constructor (possibly as I'm used to C#).

I know JavaScript is not C# but... Is it possible to make this a little more verbose?

ps. I already use TypeScript. I'm not after advice on what language is more suitable, I'm keen to learn about JavaScript and it's weird and wonderful ways :)

Comment: You may be looking for TypeScript if you're interested in static, explicit typing.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, I'm using TypeScript already, but I've only just learned today that JavaScript supports classes! As such I'm more interested in vanilla JavaScript :)  +1

Comment: JS classes are not like C# classes. It's just syntax sugar overtop of the prototype inheritance in JS. If you use a more PI approach you'll see you can do what you want. For example, read anything by Eric Elliot https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions JS `class` syntax does not change how the language works - and in JS, object properties are created dynamically and are not statically typed.

Comment: In ES2017 there's a way to initialize instance properties in the `class` declaration, but it's still just syntactic sugar. And the answer to your yes/no question about giving properties specific types is still "no".

Comment: @Bergi, thank you. That is excellent and really helped!

Comment: I played with this last night and this morning. I know understand what you mean about it being 'sugar'. I think by sugar, it's just a way to style the look of javascript but actually, it's not new functionality, it just renders it behind the scenes in the same way. There is no such thing as class, it's just a way to almost format the look of the code? @Pointy

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions right - the fundamentals of JavaScript have not really been changed by the new `class` syntax. The language committee can't make changes that cause the whole internet to break.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible in pure JS. But you could take a look at [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).
It add some functionnalities to JS and convert it to pure js.
You can :

- Have typed variable
- Specify return type
- Have enum and interface

and much more.

Comment: You can inherit classes in plain JS just as well

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of it, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-type-annotations

There is a new proposal for adding static typing to JavaScript. Currently it wouldn't change it's runtime behaviour, means types wouldn't have any effect. But seems eventually JavaScript will have native support in future.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Sorry for the abstract example (car), i could have used your example as well but you will get the point

You could utilize a getter

```
class Car {

    /**
     * static getter, can be accessed by typing Car.defaultProperties
     */
    static get defaultProperties() {
        return {
            seats: 2
        };
    }

    /**
     * prototype getter, can be called by typing this.seats or from outside...
     */
    get seats() {
        return this.properties.seats;
    }

    constructor(seats) {
        this.properties = Car.defaultProperties;
        this.properties.seats = seats;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for most IDEs with JSDoc:

https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html

So, while the Javascript itself is not typed, you do get the benefits of static analysis in the better IDEs out there. I use Visual Studio 2022, and it does an OK job of pulling in type suggestions and typeahead.

Here's an example of a strongly typed function:

```
/** 
 * @param {JQueryDeferred} ajax - Required. The return value from a jQuery AJAX call (which is always a $.Deferred).
 * @param {ajaxOnSuccess} onSuccess - Required. Equivalent to .done(), what should happen when the MVC Action was successful.
 * @param {ajaxMvcOnFail} [onFail] - Optional. Equivalent to .fail(), what should happen when the MVC Action failed.
 */
function loadMvcResult(ajax, onSuccess, onFail) {
```

So this takes 3 arguments, the last one optional. And we're doing something a little more interesting here, onSuccess and onFail are functions with parameters whose type we care about. We get to specify those as well. Here's the function definition for onSuccess:

```
/**
 * @callback ajaxOnSuccess
 * @param {MvcActionResult} r
 */
```

The `@callback` lets you strongly define a function and its parameters.

You can even define whole classes in JSDoc without ever writing any Javascript. MvcActionResult is a C# class defined on the server. We can provide strongly-typed interaction with that server-side class, passed forward in JSON, without having to clutter Javascript up with an actual class it wouldn't really instantiate directly:

```
/**
 * @typedef MvcActionResult
 * @property {boolean} Success
 * @property {string} Message
 * @property {object} ViewModel
 */
```

That lets Javascript interact in a type-safe way with the results of this Ajax call, even though the object is built in C# on the server:

```
public class MvcActionResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public class MvcActionResult<TViewModel> : MvcActionResult
{
    public TViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```